# FOSUserBundle error after installation - Symfony 3.2

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-3.2

I recently created a new project in Symfony 3.2 and installed via composer following https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html the bundle FOSUserBundle.
*(information : I used ORM)*

My problem is that after doing all those steps I have an issue on my /register/ route:

> Error: Call to a member function has() on null
> in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php at line 234

Other pieces of information : I did not touch composer.json and it was already with

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
```

Any thoughts ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Had to change

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",
```

to

```
"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.2",
```

(and composer update)